# How to make columns in a row match the column widths of the row above in a grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid, css-tables

I am trying to recreate a table effect with flexbox or any type of css grid system where the divs / cells match the width of the devs / cells in the next row regardless of content size, my current code is two rows of divs with flex on the container and flex:1 on the cell:

```
<div class="b-grid__row">
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <a href="" class="b-grid__link">
            tretregerg
        </a>
    </div>  
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <p class="b-grid__content">
            1rgeerger
        </p>
    </div>   
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <p class="b-grid__content">

        </p>
    </div>  
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <p class="b-grid__content">
            Olympia Exhibition Centre reggergreegr
        </p>
    </div>  
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <p class="b-grid__content">
            Brintex Eventser gergrege
        </p>
    </div> 
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <p class="b-grid__content">
            Jane Smith fgdfdgfdg
        </p>
    </div> 
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <p class="b-grid__content">
            jane.smith@brintexevef gfdgdfgfdgts.co.uk
        </p>
    </div> 
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <p class="b-grid__content">
            01959 525717 dfgdfgdf gdfgd
        </p>
    </div> 
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <a href="" class="l-header__user-link">
            {{ ui.icon('logout', '20', 'xx', 'one', 'l-header__logout', 'Logout') }}
        </a>
    </div>  
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <a href="" class="l-header__user-link">
            {{ ui.icon('logout', '20', 'xx', 'one', 'l-header__logout', 'Logout') }}
        </a>
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="b-grid__row">
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <a href="" class="b-grid__link">
            London wine Fair 2020
        </a>
    </div>  
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <p class="b-grid__content">
            18/05/2020
        </p>
    </div>   
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <p class="b-grid__content">
            20/05/2020
        </p>
    </div>  
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <p class="b-grid__content">
            Olympia Exhibition Centre
        </p>
    </div>  
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <p class="b-grid__content">
            Brintex Events
        </p>
    </div> 
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <p class="b-grid__content">
            Jane Smith
        </p>
    </div> 
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <p class="b-grid__content">
            jane.smith@brintexevents.co.uk
        </p>
    </div> 
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <p class="b-grid__content">
            01959 525717
        </p>
    </div> 
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <a href="" class="l-header__user-link">
            {{ ui.icon('logout', '20', 'xx', 'one', 'l-header__logout', 'Logout') }}
        </a>
    </div>  
     <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
        <a href="" class="l-header__user-link">
            {{ ui.icon('logout', '20', 'xx', 'one', 'l-header__logout', 'Logout') }}
        </a>
    </div>  
</div>


.b-grid__row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.b-grid__column-cell {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;        
}
```

This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

And this is what I need it to do:

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this while keeping the cells in separate rows?

Just to note these have to keep separate row wrappers the cannot all be in one container

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

This is a table layout:

```css
.container {
  display:table;
}

.b-grid__row {
  display: table-row;
}

.b-grid__column-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border:2px solid transparent;
  padding:5px;
  background:#fff padding-box;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.b-grid__column-cell > * {
  margin:0;
}

body {
 background:grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="b-grid__row">
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <a href="" class="b-grid__link">
            tretregerg
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <p class="b-grid__content">
      1rgeerger
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <p class="b-grid__content">

    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <p class="b-grid__content">
      Olympia Exhibition Centre reggergreegr
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <p class="b-grid__content">
      Brintex Eventser gergrege
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <p class="b-grid__content">
      Jane Smith fgdfdgfdg
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <p class="b-grid__content">
      jane.smith@brintexevef gfdgdfgfdgts.co.uk
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <p class="b-grid__content">
      01959 525717 dfgdfgdf gdfgd
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <a href="" class="l-header__user-link">
            {{ ui.icon('logout', '20', 'xx', 'one', 'l-header__logout', 'Logout') }}
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <a href="" class="l-header__user-link">
            {{ ui.icon('logout', '20', 'xx', 'one', 'l-header__logout', 'Logout') }}
        </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="b-grid__row">
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <a href="" class="b-grid__link">
            London wine Fair 2020
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <p class="b-grid__content">
      18/05/2020
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <p class="b-grid__content">
      20/05/2020
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <p class="b-grid__content">
      Olympia Exhibition Centre
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <p class="b-grid__content">
      Brintex Events
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <p class="b-grid__content">
      Jane Smith
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <p class="b-grid__content">
      jane.smith@brintexevents.co.uk
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <p class="b-grid__content">
      01959 525717
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <a href="" class="l-header__user-link">
            {{ ui.icon('logout', '20', 'xx', 'one', 'l-header__logout', 'Logout') }}
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="b-grid__column-cell b-grid__column-cell--white">
    <a href="" class="l-header__user-link">
            {{ ui.icon('logout', '20', 'xx', 'one', 'l-header__logout', 'Logout') }}
        </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```